How to dynamically compose QtCore.Qt.MatchgFlag(s) together rather than hard-coding them

I am trying to write a small app to control FastAPI server's configuration, using a dictionary. Due to the fact that I am using a QTreeView, and would like to create a search box for entering text value for the dictionary key, and asking the GUI app to expand the key, and highlight the interested key, value pair, so I can jumping to edit and change the configuration onfly. There is a search MatchFlag, but I do not know how it is implemented in C++ end, this MatchFlag doesn't behave like Python 3.9 Flag class, so I wrapped with this:
import re
from enum import Enum, Flag
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from collections import OrderedDict
from definition import Definitions as df
import logging

class GUIMatchFlag(Flag):
    SelectSearchOptions = -1
    MatchWrap = QtCore.Qt.MatchFlag.MatchWrap
    MatchRecursive = QtCore.Qt.MatchFlag.MatchRecursive
    MatchContains = QtCore.Qt.MatchFlag.MatchContains
    MatchExactly = QtCore.Qt.MatchFlag.MatchExactly
    MatchStartsWith = QtCore.Qt.MatchFlag.MatchStartsWith
    MatchEndsWith = QtCore.Qt.MatchFlag.MatchEndsWith
    MatchRegularExpression = QtCore.Qt.MatchFlag.MatchRegularExpression
    MatchWildcard = QtCore.Qt.MatchFlag.MatchWildcard
    MatchFixedString = QtCore.Qt.MatchFlag.MatchFixedString
    MatchCaseSensitive = QtCore.Qt.MatchFlag.MatchCaseSensitive

    # flag_list = None

    @classmethod
    def splitTitleChar(cls, txt: str, is_name_only=False):
        new_txt = re.sub(r'([a-z])([A-Z)])', r'\1 \2', txt)
        new_txt = (new_txt.split('.')[1] if is_name_only else new_txt)
        return new_txt


    @classmethod
    def getFlagDict(cls, is_name_only=False):
        attrib_name = ("name_only_flag_list" if is_name_only else "flag_list")
        is_init = not hasattr(cls, attrib_name)
        if is_init:
            flag_dict = OrderedDict()
            for item in GUIMatchFlag:
                split_name = cls.splitTitleChar(str(item), is_name_only=is_name_only)
                entry = {split_name: item.value}
                flag_dict.update(entry)
            setattr(cls, attrib_name, flag_dict)
        return getattr(cls, attrib_name)

    @classmethod
    def getQtFlagValue(cls, flag_name: str, is_name_only=False):
        name_to_find = cls.splitTitleChar(flag_name)
        flag_dict = cls.getFlagDict(is_name_only=is_name_only)
        find_value = flag_dict[name_to_find]
        return find_value

    @classmethod
    def getIndexForName(cls, flag_name: str, is_name_only=False):
        flag_dict = cls.getFlagDict(is_name_only=is_name_only)
        name_index_list = [(name, index) for (index, (name, value)) in enumerate(flag_dict.items()) if (name == flag_name)]
        return name_index_list[0][1]

    @classmethod
    def getQtComposeFlagValues(cls, flag_list: list[str]):
        logger.info(f'flag_list:{flag_list}')
        # local_list = [
        #     QtCore.Qt.MatchFlag.MatchWrap,
        #     QtCore.Qt.MatchFlag.MatchRecursive,
        #     QtCore.Qt.MatchFlag.MatchContains,
        #     QtCore.Qt.MatchFlag.MatchExactly,
        #     QtCore.Qt.MatchFlag.MatchStartsWith,
        #     QtCore.Qt.MatchFlag.MatchEndsWith,
        #     QtCore.Qt.MatchFlag.MatchRegularExpression,
        #     QtCore.Qt.MatchFlag.MatchWildcard,
        #     QtCore.Qt.MatchFlag.MatchFixedString,
        #     QtCore.Qt.MatchFlag.MatchCaseSensitive,
        # ]

        compose_flag = None
        for index, flag_entry in enumerate(flag_list):
            (flag_name, flag_val) = flag_entry
            # local_list_index = cls.getIndexForName(flag_name, is_name_only=True)
            # local_list_index -= 1
            # actual_flag_val = local_list[local_list_index]
            is_first = (index == 0)
            if is_first:
                compose_flag = flag_val
            else:
                compose_flag |= flag_val
        return compose_flag

and whenever the event "pressed" fired, I will call this function to update the flag:
    def searchOptionChanged(self, item:QStandardItem, is_checked: bool=False):
        item_txt = item.text()
        if not is_checked:
            try:
                del self.search_option_flag_checked_dict[item_txt]
                logger.info(f'Removing item {item_txt}')
            except KeyError as e:
                logger.info(f'Removing item {item_txt} causing exception: {e}')
        else:
            flag_dict = GUIMatchFlag.getFlagDict(is_name_only=True)
            search_flag_value = flag_dict[item_txt]
            new_search_flag_entry = {item_txt: search_flag_value}
            self.search_option_flag_checked_dict.update(new_search_flag_entry)

        flag_list = list(self.search_option_flag_checked_dict.items())
        logger.info(f'flag_list {flag_list}')
        self.search_option_flag = GUIMatchFlag.getQtComposeFlagValues(flag_list=flag_list)
        logger.info(f'search_option_flag: {self.search_option_flag}')

Here is my CheckableCombobox
from definition import Definitions as df

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from typing import Callable
from typing import Iterable
from collections import OrderedDict
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(df.LOGGING_NAME)

class CheckableComboBox(QComboBox):
    # constructor
    def __init__(self, parent=None, item_pressed_action: Callable=None):
        super(CheckableComboBox, self).__init__(parent)
        # self.setMinimumWidth(200)
        self.setMinimumContentsLength(25)
        self.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QComboBox.AdjustToContentsOnFirstShow)
        self.view().pressed.connect(self.itemPressedAction)
        self.model = QStandardItemModel(self)
        # model.itemChanged.connect(item_pressed_action)
        self.item_pressed_action = item_pressed_action
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.item_dict = None


    # action called when item get checked
    def do_action(self, item: QStandardItem, is_checked: bool=False):
        item_text = item.text()
        state_msg = (f'{item_text} is ' + "On" if is_checked else "Off")
        logger.info(state_msg)
        # when any item get pressed

    # def setOptionByList(self, flag_list: list[MatchFlag]):
    #     self.model()
    #     for flag in flag_list:
    #
    #         item: QStandardItem = self.model().itemFromIndex(index)
    #         is_checked = (item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Checked)
    #         new_state = (QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Unchecked if is_checked else QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Checked)
    #         item.setCheckState(new_state)

    def addItems(self, item_list:Iterable, ip_str=None):
        self.item_dict = OrderedDict(item_list)
        for (k, v) in self.item_dict.items():
            self.addItem(k)
        first_index: QModelIndex = self.model.index(0, 0)
        first_item: QStandardItem = self.model.itemFromIndex(first_index)
        first_item.setSelectable(False)

    def itemPressedAction(self, index: QModelIndex):
        # getting the item
        item: QStandardItem = self.model.itemFromIndex(index)

        is_first_item = index.row() == 0
        if is_first_item:
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Unchecked)
            return

        item: QStandardItem = self.model.itemFromIndex(index)
        old_state = item.checkState()
        is_checked = (old_state == QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Checked)
        new_state = (QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Unchecked if is_checked else QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Checked)

        item.setCheckState(new_state)

        is_checked = (new_state == QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Checked)
        logger.info(f'{item.text()} pressed, is_checked: {is_checked}, old_state:{old_state}, new_state:{new_state}')
        # call the action
        has_external_action = (self.item_pressed_action is not None)
        if has_external_action:
            self.item_pressed_action(item, is_checked)
        else:
            self.do_action(item, is_checked)

What I don't understand is although the values are identical, when it is passed to search function:
    def searchModelUsingName(self, search_text: QVariant, search_flag: Qt.MatchFlag):
        pattern = df.makePattern(search_text, flags=re.I)

        test_flags = GUIMatchFlag.MatchContains.value | GUIMatchFlag.MatchWrap.value | GUIMatchFlag.MatchRecursive.value
        # search_text = "GitExec"
        local_search_flag = Qt.MatchFlag.MatchContains | Qt.MatchFlag.MatchWrap | Qt.MatchFlag.MatchRecursive #::MatchContains | Qt::MatchWrap | Qt::MatchRecursive
        is_equal = (local_search_flag == test_flags)
        is_equal_search_flag = (local_search_flag == search_flag)
        logger.info(f'test_flags == local_search_flag => is_equal:{is_equal}, is_equal_search_flag:{is_equal_search_flag}')
        model: JsonModel = self.model
        is_valid_index = self.currentIndex().isValid()

        search_start_index: QModelIndex = (self.currentIndex() if is_valid_index else model.index(0, 0))
        next_matches = model.match(search_start_index,
                                   Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole,
                                   search_text,
                                   1,
                                   local_search_flag
                                   )  # supposed to be QList<QModelIndex>, or QModelIndexList
        is_found = len(next_matches) > 0
        if not is_found:
            return

        select_model: QItemSelectionModel = self.selectionModel()
        select_list: list = self.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()
        select_model.clearSelection()
        found_index: QModelIndex = None
        for found_index in next_matches:
            item_found: TreeItem = found_index.internalPointer()
            item_info: ItemInfo = item_found.getItemInfoRecord()
            tree_root: dict = item_info.root
            key_list = item_info.key_list
            key_list.reverse()
            first_level_key = key_list[0]
            has_second_key = len(key_list) > 1
            second_level_key = None
            if has_second_key:
                second_level_key = key_list[1]

            first_parent_item: TreeItem = tree_root[first_level_key]
            first_parent_item_index: QModelIndex = model.getNodeByKey(first_level_key)
            is_expanding = not self.isExpanded(first_parent_item_index)
            if is_expanding:
                self.setExpanded(first_parent_item_index, True)
            # select_model.select(first_parent_item, QItemSelectionModel.Select | QItemSelectionModel.Rows)

            if has_second_key:
                second_parent_item: TreeItem = model.getNodeByKey(second_level_key, first_parent_item_index)
                is_expanding = not self.isExpanded(second_parent_item)
                if is_expanding:
                    self.setExpanded(second_parent_item, True)
                # select_model.select(second_parent_item, QItemSelectionModel.Select | QItemSelectionModel.Rows)
            # else:
            #     select_model.select(first_parent_item, QItemSelectionModel.Select | QItemSelectionModel.Rows)
            select_model.select(found_index, QItemSelectionModel.Select | QItemSelectionModel.Rows)

the dynamically composed flag is NOT equals to the hard-coded composed flag. In the above code, it always said False, though I flagged the same flags as hard-coded one. Could someone please help me to explain why this is the case? I am using Qt5
I was expecting the hard-coded ORred flags and the dynamic ORred flags to be equal

So, are you basically asking why test_flags created with GUIMatchFlag is different from local_search_flag created with Qt.MatchFlag? If that's the case: 1. we don't need all that code, as the minimal GUIMatchFlag definition and a basic comparison will suffice; 2. test_flags is created with value, so it's just an integer, while ORed Qt.MatchFlag objects return a Qt.MatchFlags that does not inherit from int. Since you're on PyQt5, you can just compare with its integer representation: test_flags == int(local_search_flag). In PyQt6 compare with local_search_flag.value.

Thank you for coming back. It is not the comparison of two integers that I am after, when passing to the model.match() the flag is causing the function to fail, with the hard-coded OR flags, it works fine, but not with the passing in dynamically composed flags

That's because they're not real Qt.MatchFlag. You have to make them such: Qt.MatchFlag(your_value).
